# Inspiring web experiments and technical demos

Tags: html, css, flash

Probably everyone knows about Chrome Experiments:

http://www.chromeexperiments.com/

that contain some stunning examples of what JS is capable of. It would be nice to compile a collection of similar projects (usually just blog posts) that showcase some original JS/CSS/HTML/Flash or any other web-related ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Quake 2 on HTML5 Canvas http://ajaxian.com/archives/gwt-quake